# Create subquery for orderby

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have two related tables collections and items.

I want to order selected items based on collection properties.

**Collection**

```
class Collection
{
    int Id;
    string Title;
    bool Override;
    int Level;
    Datetime Till;
    int OtherProp;
    virtual ICollection<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}
```

**Item**

```
class item
{
    int Id;
    int OrderId;
    string Title;
    virtual Collection Collection{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to select all items and order them in following order:

1. All items where order override is true;
2. All items where order level equals 1 and till is les than Datetime.Now();
3. All items where order level equals 2 and till is les than Datetime.Now();
4. All other items.

It would look like

```
var resultList = await _context.Items.Where(item=> item.OtherProp == 1)
   .OrderBy(item => ??????????????)
   .ThenBy(item=> item.Title).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: It is not real classes with their navigation properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var resultList = await _context.Items
    .Where(item=> item.OtherProp == 1)
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Collection.Override)
    .ThenByDescending(item => item.Collection.Till <= Datetime.Now() && item.Collection.Level == 1)
    .ThenByDescending(item => item.Collection.Till <= Datetime.Now() && item.Collection.Level == 2)
    .ThenBy(item => item.Title)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: The issue is with the ThenByDescending clauses. Using ThenByDescending with a boolean expression will actually sort in descending order by the boolean value, not the expected sorting order.

Comment: It worked, but took too much time to do the query - just added additional column which is calculated daily in background task.

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultList = await _context.Items
    .Where(item => item.OtherProp == 1)
    .OrderBy(item =>
        item.Collection.Override ? 0 :
        (item.Collection.Level == 1 && item.Collection.Till < DateTime.Now) ? 1 :
        (item.Collection.Level == 2 && item.Collection.Till < DateTime.Now) ? 2 : 3)
    .ThenBy(item => item.Title)
    .ToListAsync();
```

You can try this query with ternary operators
It does these steps:

- If the item's collection has the Override property set to true, ordering value = 0.
- If the item's collection has Level equal to 1 and Till is less than
  DateTime.Now, ordering value = 1.
- If the item's collection has Level equal to 2 and Till is less than DateTime.Now, ordering value = 2.
- Otherwise, the item ordering value = 3.